# Spring Server/Client Sessions and Hibernate Sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session, httpsession

I use Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.6 for developing a webapplication - Im new and Im wondering if I really understand how sessions are working.

Is it correct, that the Sessions between Server and Client, identified by a session id, are different from hibernate sessions?

The session between Server and Client is always a HttpSession.(?) When is it created? When a User logs in or also when an anonymous user requests a page (which is not secured)?

is there any connection between httpsession and hibernate-sessions? Are Hibernate Sessions created by a sessionfactory with no connection to a httpsession? Im not sure to which session hibernate is refering with a command like this:

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);
```

this `getCurrentSession()`: for how long is this hibernate session active? for the whole time a user is logged in? or for just one transaction (which can include multiple data-operations?)

Im sorry for this question which is maybe totally easy to answer, but most documentations are in english and if this is not ones mother tongue understanding is sometimes difficult (mainly because the word "session" is used so often)

thanks for helping me to understand this topic! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it correct, that the Sessions
>   between Server and Client, identified
>   by a session id, are different from
>   hibernate sessions?

Yes, completely different.

**Reference:** (javax.servlet) [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), (Hibernate) [`Session`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)

> The session between Server and Client
>   is always a HttpSession.(?) When is it
>   created? When a User logs in or also
>   when an anonymous user requests a page
>   (which is not secured)?

**See** [Java EE Tutorial > Maintaining Client State](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html)

> is there any connection between
>   httpsession and hibernate-sessions?

No, although an [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) can make sure there is a Hibernate `Session` available for every HTTP Request (One Hibernate Session per Request, not per Web Session).

> Are Hibernate Sessions created by a
>   sessionfactory with no connection to a
>   httpsession?

Yes, usually.

> Im not sure to which
>   session hibernate is refering with a
>   command like this:
>   "this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);"

Hibernate `Session`

> this "getCurrentSession()": for how
>   long is this hibernate session active?
>   for the whole time a user is logged
>   in? or for just one transaction (which
>   can include multiple data-operations?)

**See** [Hibernate Reference > Session and Transaction Scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. reading through the sources you gave me, I got some more questions: 

1. when HttpSession is an interface, how can an "object of HttpSession" than represent a session? Mustn't there be a concrete class which implements HttpSession?

Comment: 2. I might be stupid, but did I understand correctly, that a session is created when a user connects for the first time with the server (without having a session id). he must not be logged in for it. the sessions ends when it times out (for example after 30min) or when the user (if he was logged in) logs out

Comment: 3. normally, when nothing specific is configured, one hibernate session is created for one requests. is a hibernate session also automatically created for a requests when not database operation is done? 

thank you :-)

Comment: 1) There are concrete classes, but you're not supposed to use them. It's up to your Servlet Container to provide the specific implementation class. If you code against that concrete class, you break compatibility with other app servers. 2) depends on app server configuration 3) is only correct if using OpenSessionInViewFilter. Usually, Hibernate based web apps need an open Hibernate Session for every single request

Comment: thanks! 2) where can I see how it is configured? I use tomcat 6 and I did not make any special configurations.. 3) maybe we are at cross purposes or I dont understand: I thought, without OpenSessionInViewFilter and without any specific configuration, usually One Session Per Request is used, right? -> is there an open source tool where I can monitor hibernate sessions with? (maybe bound to httpsessions?)

Comment: 2) I'm not an expert at that, ask a separate question or read the docs 3) no, without OSIVF, hibernate sessions and web requests / sessions don't have anything to do with each other